# How to check status of RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a program whch has several RegularExpressionValidators which are filtering out the non numeric input of the users.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" class="errorMess" ErrorMessage="Letters are not Allowed!!" ControlToValidate="CelNo" ValidationExpression="\d+" runat="server" />
```

However I observed that RegularExpressionValidators only printing out error messages but not hindering a user from the input of the wrong data.

Therefore i was woundering how can I validate RegularExpressionValidator at the backend code, in order to put restriction before i pass the value into the query.

Like for example If the message is visible, execution will stop. Of course there are some other ways how to filter out non numeric data. But I just want to discuss doing it through RegularExpressionValidator .

I tried it like this. But can't understand why is it not working:

```
    If RegularExpressionValidator1.IsValid Then

        MsgBox("Ya")

    Else
        MsgBox("Niht")
    End If
```

And this is the front end code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="CelNo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
   <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ErrorMessage="Letters are not Allowed!!" ControlToValidate="CelNo" ValidationExpression="\d+"
        runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check it by using `Page.IsValid`...like

```
if(Page.IsValid)
{
   //your Stff
}
else
{
   //show your notification
}
```

or you can do like this....

```
if(YourRegularExpressionId.IsValid==true)
{
   //your Stff
}
else
{
   //show your notification
}
```

Comment: But how is that connected to the RegularExpressionValidator?

Comment: when ever a validation fails page.isvalid becomes false

Comment: talking about RegularExpressionValidators can we set it up to check length or lets say bind it to the function?

Comment: sorry i can not understand what u said above

Comment: what I mean is I'm cheching numeric input using RegularExpressionValidator. How about if I want to check the length of the text using the same tool. is it possible?

Comment: I tried this in VB. But no reaction `If Page.IsValid = True Then

            MsgBox("Ya")

        Else
            MsgBox("Niht")
        End If`

Comment: i dont know why it doesnt work .....anyway try like    `RegularExpressionValidator1.IsValid`

Comment: I have a question Amit, lets say I have several RegularExpressionValidators. do I have to validate them 1 by one or I can validate the whole page at once?

Comment: I tried the new code of yours still not working `If RegularExpressionValidator1.IsValid = True Then

            MsgBox("Ya")

        Else
            MsgBox("Niht")
        End If`

Comment: to validate whole page at once you can use `Page.Isvald` which is i dont know why not working....in your case

Comment: then there is problem in regular expession it not geting false

Comment: I find a link with a tutorial on validation. However I can't declare BrowsableAttribute `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.isvalid.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1`

Comment: its validation belongs to any group

Comment: you didnt define the calidation group of your validator

Comment: for trial purposes I tried it in a separated page with only one regularexpression validator. I update my post putting your code there. But I don't know why its not working in my case

Comment: no I didn't hereis the code for validator: `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" class="errorMess" ErrorMessage="Letters are not Allowed!!" ControlToValidate="CelNo" ValidationExpression="\d+" runat="server" />`

Comment: RegularExpressionValidator1.Validate() remove it

Comment: i think you are not entring anything in your textbox...enter something in textbox then validate

Comment: no I'm entering some text. if there are symbols the message `letters are not allowed` are being printed. But when i press button i can.t see any reaction

Comment: if doesnt postback if your validation fails

Comment: I have some progress actually if I enter only numbers the messageBox `MsgBox("Ya")` is shown. It means the else part of the conditional statement is not working. what do you think?

Comment: friend it working fine....it doesn't call you page event when validation fails it doesnt allow you to postback till it is not valid so it workning fine

Comment: debug it you will see you function doesnt call when your validation fails..it shows only error message

Comment: so sow can I enter the else part?

Comment: why you wana enter else part ....it error messge wil do the work of your else part....

Comment: because the cause was to print the error message in case it's not valid. But I can only acess true part. else part is not reacting

Comment: `ErrorMessage="Letters are not Allowed!!"` will print the message

Comment: you can not...alert message from code behind when validation failed but insted you want to show from code behind than use `customvalidator` instead regular expressino validator

Comment: because I want to limit it from passing the entry to the database. and what condition can I specify to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: if anyone else encounters the problem that Page.IsValid is always true then, 

my problem was solved by this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9145235/9227605